Tailwind CSS Issue with displaying radio buttons in Safari
I have a problem that I don't understand how to solve.
I have radio buttons to which I have added Tailwind CSS classes and on a pc they look correct, but from a phone, in Sarafi browser they have a different look. How can I achieve an identical design as on pc? Attached images
<div class="cursor-pointer border-b border-t py-4 px-4">
  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
    <div class="flex items-center space-x-2"><input class="border-accent-black h-4 w-4 cursor-pointer rounded-full accent-black" type="radio" id="1" name="shipping_method_id" value="1" checked="" /><label class="cursor-pointer font-medium">Shipping</label></div>
    <div class="flex gap-1 font-medium uppercase"><span>FREE</span></div>
  </div>
  <p class="mt-1 pl-6 text-gray-500"></p>
</div>

Minimal representation:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/XK7kJMsOms


I expect to get a look identical to the PC version

the input tag you use is represented to use built-in input HTML element browser. The built-in HTML input style varies between browsers, with each browser having different styles. To solve you must create your own element. you can see this library if you use react. it will render the same in different browser https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/radio-group
